# Print only JSON Values returned from MySql query in nodejs

Tags: mysql, arrays, json, node.js

I want to retrieve records from mysql and display data on my page coded in nodejs with format

```
 [
    ["1262889000000",788,803,783.3,795.65],
    ["1262889000000",788,813,783.3,795.65],
    ["1451500200000",2.85,13,1.05,1.1],
    ........
 ]
```

my table schema

```
Column1           |   col2   |   col3   |    col4     |   col5

1262889000000          788       783.3        794          65  
1262889000000          788       813.7        795          65 
...........
...........
```

Here is my nodejs code

```
app.get('/charts/sample1', function(req, res) {

    con.query("select col1,col2,col3,col4,col5 from table1", function(err, data) {
    res.send(data);
    }); 

 });
```

however currently when run my code i get out in json alng with {key1:value,key2:value,...},

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to map the object values in each row to an array?

Something like this? :

```
var rows = [{
    Column1: 1262889000000,
    col2: 788,
    col3: 783.3,  
    col4: 794,
    col5: 65
}];

var result = rows.map((row) => {
    return Object.values(row);
});

console.log(result);
```

Here's a JSFiddle for this: https://jsfiddle.net/y0vpad3b/

Comment: Cool, glad to help!!